# Laravel 4 and Angular JS and Twitter Bootstrap 3 Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

***Edit:***

I need a pagination in my Laravel 4 - Angular JS application which is structured using twitter bootstrap 3. You may suggest the [angularui-bootstrap pagination](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination). But I am not planning to use this right now. I need to explore and utilize the features of Laravel pagination with angular.js. I have seen one blog [article here](http://kirkbushell.me/pagination-with-laravel-4-and-angular-js/) which describe the same. But my bad luck, it is not working and there is a lot of mistakes in the article.

So based on that article, I have a Laravel controller function which uses [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination) like this, Please not that, I am converting my return data to array using `toArray()`.

```
class CareerController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $careers = Career::paginate( $limit = 10 );
        return Response::json(array(
            'status'  => 'success',
            'message' => 'Careers successfully loaded!',
            'careers' => $careers->toArray()),
            200
        );
    }
}
```

Now see how it is loaded the data in my Firebug console using angularjs REST http `$resource` call,

[image: firebug console]

Here I have some pagination details such as `total`, `per_page`, `current_page`, `last_page`, `from` and `to` including my `data`.

And now look what I am doing in angular script,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']); // Module for the app
// Set root url to use along the scripts
app.factory('Data', function(){
    return {
        rootUrl: "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/"
    };
});
// $resource for the career controller
app.factory( 'Career', [ '$resource', 'Data', function( $resource, Data ) {
   return $resource( Data.rootUrl + 'api/v1/careers/:id', { id: '@id'}, {
    query: {
        isArray: false,
        method: 'GET'
    }
   });
}]);
// the career controller
function CareerCtrl($scope, $http, Data, Career) {
    // load careers at start
    $scope.init = function () {

        Career.query(function(response) {   
            $scope.careers = response.careers.data;  
            $scope.allCareers = response.careers; 

        }, function(error) {

            console.log(error);

            $scope.careers = [];
        }); 

    };
}
```

And my view,

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9" ng-controller="CareerCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">      
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th width="4">S.No</th>
                  <th>Job ID</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="career in careers">
                  <td style="text-align:center">{{ $index+1 }}</td>
                  <td>{{ career.job_id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ career.job_title }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-show="careers.length == 0">
                  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center"> No Records Found..!</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div paginate="allCareers"></div>
</div><!--/row-->
```

And the paginate directive,

```
app.directive( 'paginate', [ function() {
    return {
      scope: { results: '=paginate' },
      template: '<ul class="pagination" ng-show="totalPages > 1">' +
               '  <li><a ng-click="firstPage()">&laquo;</a></li>' +
               '  <li><a ng-click="prevPage()">&lsaquo;</a></li>' +
               '  <li ng-repeat="n in pages">' +
               '    <a ng-bind="n" ng-click="setPage(n)">1</a>' +
               '  </li>' +
               '  <li><a ng-click="nextPage()">&rsaquo;</a></li>' +
               '  <li><a ng-click="last_page()">&raquo;</a></li>' +
               '</ul>',
      link: function( scope ) {
       var paginate = function( results ) {
         if ( !scope.current_page ) scope.current_page = 0;

         scope.total = results.total;
         scope.totalPages = results.last_page;
         scope.pages = [];

         for ( var i = 1; i <= scope.totalPages; i++ ) {
           scope.pages.push( i ); 
         }

         scope.nextPage = function() {
           if ( scope.current_page < scope.totalPages ) {
             scope.current_page++;
           }
         };

         scope.prevPage = function() {
           if ( scope.current_page > 1 ) {
             scope.current_page--;
           }
         };

         scope.firstPage = function() {
           scope.current_page = 1;
         };

         scope.last_page = function() {
           scope.current_page = scope.totalPages;
         };

         scope.setPage = function(page) {
           scope.current_page = page;
         };
       };

       var pageChange = function( newPage, last_page ) {
         if ( newPage != last_page ) {
           scope.$emit( 'page.changed', newPage );
         }
       };

       scope.$watch( 'results', paginate );
       scope.$watch( 'current_page', pageChange );
     }
   }
 }]);
```

Now I am getting maximum 10 records in my html table, the pagination links are not working.

Console shows `Error: results is undefined` with the pagination directive.

Comment: A plunker or fiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: Try to initialize `careers` property at the beginning of the `CareerCtrl`: `function CareerCtrl($scope, $http, Data, Career) { $scope.careers = []; ...`

Comment: Can you make your http://azureits.com/cms/api/v1/careers/ return Content Type of "application/json"?

Comment: @marcoseu See in my controller, I am using laravel's json response ``return Response::json(array(
            'status'  => 'success',
            'message' => 'Careers successfully loaded!',
            'careers' => $careers->toArray()),
            200
        );``. The doc http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/Rd8MG/6/ . There is an error with getting careers info due to same origin policy. Try the code on your machine.

Comment: @Alexei Ok, it shows the 10 data like before and also shows the pagination buttons. But nothing happens when I click those links.

Comment: @Alexei If required, check this also http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8MG/7/ . And see the career service portion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prepared a working example for your case http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/Rd8MG/101/
Change `Career` service for your code to work.
Hope this will help you
**EDIT:**
Edited jsfiddle with index number http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/Rd8MG/106/

Comment: Can you add some code to continue serial number in second page? I need ``11 and 12`` instead of ``1 and 2`` in page 2.

Comment: It shows the same..``1 and 2``. we have from variable in laravel output right?

Comment: May be you see old fiddle? On fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/Rd8MG/106/ page 1 starts with serial number 1, page 2 - with 11, page 33 - with 21

Comment: Did the fiddle solve the main problem of the question - problem with pagination? Does the pagination work?

Comment: @Alexi When I run the code in jsfiddle it's not working, may be some cross domain issue. But the pagination works in my server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41618/discussion-between-alexei-and-idevoc)

Comment: @Alexi I am trying to use my pagination directive for all operations, so I can't call ajax inside directive. Can you try to fix it here http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8MG/112/

Comment: I tried your example with AngularJS 1.3.0 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't bound your careers to results. Just make it:
`paginate="careers"` instead. However, I did realise there's a mistake there in my original article as well - and that is that in your paginate directive, where it defines scope - it should look like this:

```
scope: { results: '=paginate' },
```

What this is doing, is telling our directive to bind "results" to the $scope object, like so:

```
$scope.results
```

This will then bind to the result set (in this case, careers) and use that as the basis for the pagination work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You mean to replace ``scope: { results: '&' }`` with ``scope: { results: '&paginate' }`` ?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean. Check my updated response, it should be =paginate also, not &paginate as per my original response (sorry for the confusion).

The main problem is you're not passing the result set to paginate, which it uses to look at the properties of the paginated object response from laravel, and creates all the links/navigation.etc.

Comment: Now I am getting ``Error: results is undefined...``
On this line of code ``scope.totalPages = results.last_page;`` of the directive.

Comment: Please do not mark down my responses - my responses are correct. It's the original code off my article that is incorrect (and needs to be updated). In addition, it's actually your code that is incorrect and in need of updating (in this particular instance).

I cannot help you unless provide all the code. As per my original comment, please update your code with the &paginate line as per my original response.

Comment: You don't down vote someone if the answer does not fix the problem. It seems like you are over your head @iDevoc if you are new to Angular.

Comment: It's a blog post, not an authoritative source, everyone makes mistakes. He has tried to help you over an extended period of time. He's spent his time and effort to help you, down voting him is uncalled for.

Comment: You're assigning "careers" to the paginator, which does not represent the paginator instance. It represents the dataset of the records of careers for that "page".

What you need to pass to the paginator, is the full careers object, including all the pagination data. Without it, it cannot do anything, and is why it's not working.

My blog post may be incorrect (if you check the comments on the actual post you'll see a few people had the same problem). Unfortunately for those people, I have not had time to update it, and it was quite some time ago AND it's now outdated thanks to Laravel 4.1.

Comment: @Oddman Thanks for suggestion, I think already corrected here http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8MG/14/ . Please check this again I am getting error.