# Angularjs: scope.data is undefined inside directive

Tags: angularjs

First off, i found the api address from this topic:
[Laravel 4 and Angular JS and Twitter Bootstrap 3 Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817540/laravel-4-and-angular-js-and-twitter-bootstrap-3-pagination)

Now i am working about this, my little script is so:

```
var app = angular.module('kategori', [
        'ngResource',
        'apiBaseRoute'
    ]);

    app.factory('Data', ['$resource', 'apiBaseRoute', function($resource, config){
        return $resource('http://develop.alexei.me/careers/careers.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&page=:page', {
            page: 1
        }, {
            'get': {
                method: 'JSONP'
            }
        });
    }]);

    app.controller('KategoriListCtrl', function($scope, Data){

        $scope.init = function() {
          Data.get({}, function(response){
              $scope.kategoriList = response.careers;


          },function(error){
              console.log("HATA VAR" + error);
          });
        };

    });

    app.directive('paginate', function(){
        return{
            scope:{ allData: '=paginate2' },
            link: function(scope){
                console.log(scope);
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the html side :

```
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" ng-controller="KategoriListCtrl" ng-init="init()">
                {{kategoriList}}
                <div paginate paginate2="kategoriList"></div>
            </div>
```

as you see, console.log(scope) inside directive is shows a lot of things in console, especially i see allData there with lots data, but if i change it to

```
console.log(scope.allData)
```

it prints  undefined..

i don't understand why. how can i solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By the time JS reaches your `console.log` the `allData` property is undefined (since `kategoriList` is undefined). `kategoriList` (and thus `allData`) is created (and populated with lots of data) asynchronously at a later time.

So, why do you see the data when logging the `scope` object instead ?

At the time the object is logged it has no property `allData` (and no data).
**But** by the time you go over to the console and expand the node and look for the `allData` property, the property has been added and populated by your AJAX call (using `$resource`).

---

It is not clear what you want to do with `allData`.
If you want to use it in e.g. `ng-repeat` you don't have to worry: You can use it normally (as if it were defined) and Angular will automatically "pick it up" as soon as it arrives and do stuff.
Yet, if you want (for your own mysterious reasons) to get informed when it is ready, your can use **[`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)**:

```
scope.$watch('allData', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
        console.log(scope.allData);
    }
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6tDmD/)**.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i am trying to do pagination system, i will use current_page, etc..  inside directive. i see data without directive normally, with ng-repeat as you said, but i couldnt transfer data into the directive.

Comment: OK. Still this does not clarify how you plan on using `allData`. If you face any problem post the relevant code. BTW, if this post answered your question, please mark it as "accepted".

Comment: i would create two variables one of them would contain only data which will show in the page. other will contain pagination data which came from laravel. allData is variable for pagination data ( page, current_page, last_page, total_page etc..)

Comment: You shouldn't face any difficulties. Still, if you run into problems, post a new question providing the relevant code.